# S3 storage class: What is the actual difference between STANDARD and STANDARD_IA?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What is the technical difference between these two storage classes? That is, how do their implementations differ?

Comment: This should answer that question: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/storage-classes

Comment: @Brian unfortunately it doesn't. I'd like to know how the  _implementations_ differ.

Comment: @OronNavon, when you say "implementations", do you mean how have Amazon implemented the two storage tiers?

Comment: @GreenyMcDuff yes - at least the difference between STANDARD and STANDARD-IA.

Comment: I don't want to sound flippant but you'd probably need to ask Amazon Tech support, and then they would probably tell you to go do one :)

Comment: This is an excellent question. The two storage classes give exactly the same data durability and availability guarantees, so my assumption is that they are identical apart from pricing. I'd like to hear it from the horse's mouth though.

Comment: https://tutorialsdojo.com/s3-standard-vs-s3-standard-ia-vs-s3-one-zone-ia/

Answer (score 0):

The 2 main difference is that with the Standard-IA S3, the minimum charge on your files is 30 days AND there is a retrieval fee. This means that if you uploaded a file called `cat.png` to Standard-IA for 18 days and deleted it, they will still charge you for 30 days (18 days + 12 days) + retrieval fee.